# How can I get a screenshot of what's on my AppleTV?

Tags: appletv

Preferably Wirelessly. Any apps for that?

Obviously I'm talking about the more recent iOS powered little black box AppleTV, not the original model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know AppleTV has no capabilities for this. What I've done is simply to take a photo of the TV screen.

Answer (score 4):

After some [quick Googling](http://forum.firecore.com/topic/7637) I found these steps:

- Jailbreak
- Install aTV Flash (black)
- Install nitoTV
- Install 'screencapture' (through nitoTV)
- SSH in: `ssh root@Apple-TV.local` (or `ssh root@ipaddress`, e.g. `ssh root@192.168.3.61`)
- At this point typing in `screencapture` SHOULD save Screenshot.png to root. If it does not you may need to change ownership on root via: chown mobile:staff ./

Obviously less than ideal, but possible.

Comment: I'll up vote this, but I'm looking for a non-jailbreak answer, so not going to mark as accepted...